# What is 'keyword' is missing from this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, keyword

This is what I have;

```
SELECT c.customerFN, c.customerEmail, p.productName, 
SUM(p.unitsonstock + p.unitsordered) AS "All Units"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN order o
 WHERE c.customerID=o.customerID
INNER JOIN orderDetails d 
 WHERE o.orderID=d.orderID
INNER JOIN product p
 WHERE p.productCode=l.productCode
WHERE orderDate <= '2015-03-15'
 ORDER BY productName;
```

When I enter this the database throws a "missing keyword" error at the fourth line. Could you tell me what it is that I'm missing

Comment: `ON` clause is missing.

Comment: where would I implement the ON clause? thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` is performed using the `ON` clause, not with a `WHERE`:

```
...
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN order o ON c.customerID=o.customerID
INNER JOIN orderDetails d ON o.orderID=d.orderID
INNER JOIN product p ON p.productCode=d.productCode
WHERE orderDate <= '2015-03-15'    
...
```

The `WHERE` clause that comes *after* join should be used like you have it in your query.

Apart from the problem with the `JOIN` there is also a problem using `SUM` without grouping. You probably want something like:

```
SELECT c.customerFN, c.customerEmail, p.productName, 
       SUM(p.unitsinstock + p.unitsordered) AS "All Units"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN order o ON c.customerID=o.customerID
INNER JOIN orderDetails d ON o.orderID=d.orderID
INNER JOIN product p ON p.productCode=d.productCode
WHERE orderDate <= '2015-03-15'
GROUP BY customerFN, customerEmail, productName
ORDER BY p.productName;
```

Use of `SUM` function implies a `GROUP BY` clause. Every column selected that is not part of an aggregate function like `SUM` must be present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `WHERE` in line 5, 7 and 9 you need to use `ON`. You are also using function `SUM`, but there is no `GROUP BY`. Change your query like this:

```
SELECT c.customerFN, c.customerEmail, p.productName, 
SUM(p.unitsonstock + p.unitsordered) AS "All Units"
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN order o
ON c.customerID=o.customerID
INNER JOIN orderDetails d 
ON o.orderID=d.orderID
INNER JOIN product p
ON p.productCode=l.productCode
WHERE orderDate <= '2015-03-15'
GROUP BY c.customerFN, c.customerEmail, p.productName
ORDER BY p.productName;
```

Comment: error at line one: ORA-00937: not a single-group group funtion.
Ive been fighting that for twenty minutes

Comment: @Skersh I updated the answer, it should be working now